# Fixing "-Wunused-parameter" warning which depends on pre-processor conditions

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c-preprocessor, compiler-warnings

How to fix the "-Wunused-parameter" warning when the use of variable depends on the preprocessor-directive(#if, #else ...) conditions.

```
void foo(std::string& color)
{
#ifdef PRINT
    printf("Printing color: ", color);
#endif
}
```

I have seen the usage of (void) like:

```
void foo(std::string& color)
{
#ifdef PRINT
    printf("Printing color: ", color);
#else
    (void)color;
#endif
}
```

Is this the right way?

[ Note ]: The example mentioned here is a very low illustration of my actual use case.

Comment: I would recommend that you use normal if conditions instead, if possible. This of course requires that `PRINT` is always defined as either truthy or falsy value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really prefer to use [std::ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple> // for std::ignore

void foo(std::string& color)
{
    #ifdef PRINT
        printf("Printing color: ", color.c_str());
    #else
        std::ignore = color;
        printf("Not printing any color");
    #endif
}
```

Now, to be honest, it is advised that std::ignore [has not been designed for that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore), so the actual solution should still be to "`(void)` cast" the unused variable.

With C++17, you also have another alternative, [attributes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes), in particular [`maybe_unused`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo([[maybe_unused]] std::string& color) // 
{
    #ifdef PRINT
        printf("Printing color: %s", color.c_str());
    #else
        printf("Not printing any color");
    #endif
}

int main()
{ 
  std::string color("red");
  foo(color);
}
```

[**See it running**](https://www.onlinegdb.com/H1rKLHITU)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `(void) variable` is a simple way to avoid unused variable warnings, e.g: around `assert`s. An alternative solution is to change the way print is defined:

```
#if defined PRINT
#define PRINTF(str) printf("%s\n", str)
#else
#define PRINTF(str) (void)str;
#endif
```